# Error when create jhipster sample 21-points application

Tags: node.js, jhipster

Follow the official guide I installed nodejs, yoman, bower, gulp and generator-jhipster in my mac. After executed "yo jhipster" command it shows something error occured. Where is wrong? I can run "./mvnw" and startup server but the home page hints me there is something error.

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g bower
npm install -g gulp
npm install -g generator-jhipster
yo jhipster
...
bootstrap#3.3.7 src/main/webapp/bower_components/bootstrap
└── jquery#3.1.0
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn gulp ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be `npm install -g gulp-cli`

See the [doc](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/):

> Install Gulp: npm install -g gulp-cli (If you have previously
>   installed a version of gulp globally, please run npm rm -g gulp to
>   make sure your old version doesn’t collide with gulp-cli)

Also take care of using an LTS version of NodeJS.